Error: Could not find or load main class runners.CukesRunner Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: runners.CukesRunner
I get this error while dockerizing my java automation codes Error: Could not find or load main class runners.CukesRunner
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: runners.CukesRunner
(https://i.sstatic.net/rYMFekZ1.png)
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.10.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
        <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

<!-- Maven Surefire Plugin for running tests -->
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
            <extent.reporter.spark.start>true</extent.reporter.spark.start>
            <extent.reporter.stark.out>test-output/reports/test-automation-report.html</extent.reporter.stark.out>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
        <includes>
            <include>**/CukesRunner.java</include>
        </includes>
        <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
        <runOrder>alphabetical</runOrder>
        <parallel>methods</parallel>
        <threadCount>3</threadCount>
        <perCoreThreadCount>true</perCoreThreadCount>
    </configuration>
</plugin>


FROM maven:3.9.9-eclipse-temurin-17 AS build


WORKDIR /app


COPY pom.xml ./
COPY src ./src


RUN mvn clean package


FROM eclipse-temurin:17-jdk AS runtime

WORKDIR /app


COPY --from=build /app/target/*.jar app.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar","../src/test/java/runners/CukesRunner.java"]

How can ı fix this error
